# Why mouseup event didn't fire for child element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Given the DOM with some divs:

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="graph">

  </div>
  <div id="devices">
    <div class="device">
      Display
    </div>
    <div class="device">
      Server
    </div>
    <div class="device">
      Player
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div id="indicator1" class="indicator">
indicator1
</div>
<div id="indicator2" class="indicator" style="background : aqua;">
indicator2
</div>
```

The div with class 'device' has the following 'mousedown' handler:

```
function itemChoose(evt) {
  item = this;
  inPageX = evt.pageX;
  inPageY = evt.pageY;
  $(item).css('position', 'relative');
  $('#main').on('mousemove', drag);
  $('#graph').on('mousemove', show2);
  $('#main').on('mouseup', clear1);
  $('#graph').on('mouseup', clear2);
}
```

This handler is supposed to allow to move the 'device' element by mouse. The process of moving is OK, but 'mouseup' event fires only for '#main' div which is parent of '#graph' div. The question is: why 'mouseup' event didn't fire for '#graph' div?
The example sketch is here: https://jsfiddle.net/beem/w49L14t3/1/.
Here the 2 bottom 'indicator' divs show the text 'cleared' when the '#main' or '#graph' div fire 'mouseup' event, respectively.
Tested on Chromium 47.0.2526.73 and Firefox 43.

Comment: try changing the sequence of registering the event listeners. 

$('#graph').on('mousemove', show2);
$('#graph').on('mouseup', clear2); 
$('#main').on('mousemove', drag);
$('#main').on('mouseup', clear1);

Answer (score 0):

It seems like 'mouseup' event fires in draggable '.device' div then in it's parent '#devices' div then in it's parent '#main' div. This can be seen from my next version of snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/beem/w49L14t3/4 .

```
  $('#main').on('mouseup', clear1);
  $('#graph').on('mouseup', clear2);
  $('#devices').on('mouseup', clear3);
```

So the '#graph' div stays out of event path.